# PHP: Session cookie issue between subdirectories

Tags: php, session, cookies, shared-hosting

My problem is that multiple session cookies are generated for the same user and browser/tab.

I have a init.php file, which is the only file responsible for starting sessions,  the first few lines of said file looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
...
...?>
```

This file is located at /include/init.php, which itself is in a subdirectory.

i then have a another php file located at /include/phpjson/memberInfo.php.

This file, like all the other files, includes the init.php file. But as soon as this file is executed, another session cookie shows up in the tmp directory.

The problem isn't just that another session cookie is created, but also that my main pages located at root now seems to be using a different session than the ones located in any subdirectory.

after searching stackoverflow and other sites on google, i found that some people recommended using the **session_set_cookie_params** function to set the path for the session cookies. However, since all the session cookies were already in the same folder, this didn't have any effect.

I understand that whichever file including the init.php will run the containing code from the file itself, not from where init.php is originally located. Which explains why all the files in root seem to be sharing the same session.

The simple solution here is to have every php script in the root directory, but this doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

If there are any questions regarding this issue please ask in the comments. I will try to respond to them as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards
Daniel Holst

Comment: Do you use `include`, `include-once`, `require`, or `require-once` to call init.php?

Comment: I just use include. Should I be doing otherwise ?

Comment: Also, have you verified that it is in fact separate sessions (because that seems odd). If not, create a $_SESSION var, then try to call it from a subpage.

Comment: Generally speaking `require_once` is the way to go with something like this. Because it won't let the page run if unable to call file (the session is fairly important so this is good) and the "_once" part means that it won't call the file again if it has already done so.

Comment: As far as I can see they are seperate sessions with different session  Ids and different content. It is worth mentioning that when people visit the website a session variable called timezone is set. But this only happens if it isn't already set

Comment: Are you manually setting the session name or id?

Comment: No. I was hoping php would handle that for me. I only need one session per user

Comment: Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php `session_start()` will resume a session if one already exists, so something somewhere is causing it to disregard this and make a new one. Unfortunately I can't think of anything off the top of my head without view code. Try changing to `require_once`, that may fix it, and if not, no harm done.

Comment: can it be that you kill the session by yourself ?... just a question, no more..

Comment: The only place I destroy an or unset a session is in the logout script

Comment: @amflare I will have to get back to you tomorrow with the results of that since I've basically gone to bed. And am current responding with my phone :)
But I will definitely try that first thing in the morning